# Find sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have problem with finding sum of this series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1})}
$$
I tried to try to reformulate is something to telescope it, because it's pretty much the only method of finding sums I know. But no success so far.

Comment: Multiply with $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)} (\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1})} = \frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = \frac1{\sqrt{n}} - \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

The sum of which telescopes.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$ you get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)} (\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+1})} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}} - \frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\\
= \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} = \ldots - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
which is a so-called [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and equals $$1 - \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} = 1 - 0 = 1$$